# Speed of bit operations with bit operators

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

Suppose I have

```
x &(num-1)
```

where x is an unsigned long long and num a regular int and & is the bitwise and operator.

I'm getting a significant speed reduction as the value of num increases.  Is that normal behavior?

These are the other parts of the code that are affected

```
int* hash = new int[num]
```

Comment: How did you measure? Please post your timing code.

Comment: What sort of speed reduction?  Does the speed suddenly increase when the size of num reaches a particular level, e.g. > "what can be represented by a byte"?

Comment: Code is too long..It is part of a much larger program (hash table) that incorporates that operation.  It's just when i increases the number of n by a powers of 2, the program slows down...alot

Comment: Are you sure you have narrowed it down to this operation? It can not be any other part of the long code you're referring to?

Comment: The only part of the code that gets changed IS the value of num.  I have confirmed it...unless allocating more on the heap can slow down a program..

Comment: Yes, but what about the result of the line you posted? Does it affect anything else? Please try narrowing down your code and post it.

Comment: I edited my post to reflect the other area it affects..Besides that there is nothing else

Comment: What does your timing code look like? Does it include the allocation you have just posted?

Comment: So you are alloating an array and don't do anything with it that depends on its size? What purpose does it serve then?

Comment: I don't know what the value of 'num' is, but might it not be the allocation that is taking time? And what is a "significant speed reduction"?

Comment: I'm allocating an array of that size...Then I'm using x&(num-1) to get the index of the array of where I should insert items.  It doesn't serve any other purpose.

Comment: @bart...that is a possibility as well

Comment: Yes, allocating a large block can easily take more time.  There will be a huge bump when you exceed what can be satisfied by the CRT heap and the heap has to request additional space from the OS.  Beyond that, the OS may also have to zero out the memory it issues to your process.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the bitwise operation is slowing down, I think you're using it a lot more times.  And probably it isn't even the bitwise operation that's taking too long, but whatever else you're also doing more times.

Use a profiler.

Comment: That number is not part of any loop or iterator whatsoever...It is only used to allocated more heap space

Answer (score 2):

If you're executing the code in a tight loop, it's wholly possibly that you'll see the performance lessen the higher num gets, I'm *guessing* that your C++ compiler isn't able to find a native instruction to perform the & with an unsigned long long - as you've stated your getting a slowdown for each power of two then I'd expect that the code that results from the & is repeatedly "dividing num" by 2 until it's zero and performing the and bit-by-bit.

Another possibility is that the CPU you're running on is lame and doesn't perform AND in a fixed number of cycles.

Comment: @ralu - not that I know of, am sure such CPUs exist, though - even if they're only sat idle in attics in old ZX81s.

Comment: ...I stand corrected, the ZX81 (with Z80 CPU) took a consistent 7 cycles to perform an AND.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  It had to do with the CPU cache and locality.